# Progress bar made of solid line, with dots as steps

Tags: html, css, svg, css-shapes

I'm trying to create a vertical progress-bar, with 8 dots on a solid line (with the 8th on the end), where every dot stands for one step in the process. See attached screenshot (in the bottom to prevent this question will be broken up).

Of course I have tried to make some stuff in HTML and CSS, which you can see in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fbh0xnpp/) (code below). The problem with this is, that I can't find a way to create the 7 dots on the light-green line, without adding 8 more divs (8 because the first also has to be there).

Functionality-wise, I want JS to check the `value` of the `progressNow`-div, multiplay it by 100 and add that as a CSS-height to the `progressNow`-class. Problem with this is that the dot will move, instead of the bar filling up. (does this make sense?)

This has made me think of creating an SVG element in the shape you can see in the screenshot, that has a gradient that changes location based on the nth step in the process. I know this will work and I know I can get it to work, but I was wondering if there's another, maybe easier, way to achieve what I'm trying to achieve.

**HTML**

```
<div id="progress">
    <div class="progressBar"></div>
    <div class="progressNow" value="1"></div>
    <div class="progressTotal"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#progress {
    position: relative;
}

#progress .progressBar {
    height: 800px;
    width: 6px;
    background: #8fe4bf;
    position: absolute;
}

#progress .progressNow {
    height: 100px;
    width: 6px;
    background: #00b164;
    position: absolute;
}

#progress .progressNow::after {
    content: "";
    width: 16px;
    height: 16px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background: #00b164;
    display: block;
    margin-left: -5px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 90px;
}
```

**Desired result** (in this case, the `value` of `progressNow` is `2`)

[image]

Comment: Maybe using a order list should be more easy to achieve you want - <ul> should be the  left line and li´s are the dots. Just a thought!

Comment: You can check out this tutorial. I had to make one recently and I kind of pieced something together based off of this: **[Multistep From w/ Progress](http://thecodeplayer.com/walkthrough/jquery-multi-step-form-with-progress-bar)**

Comment: just CSS and still a <progress> bar ? http://codepen.io/anon/pen/xwRyrm

Comment: @GCyrillus: That's a very neat one. Why didn't you post as answer?

Comment: I was not sure about what you looked for, i'll make an answer of it :)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

My solution is similar to @Stewartside's, except it uses Flexbox to position everything equally.  It's also really easy to change the height.

```css
ul.progress-bar {
  height: 300px;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
  overflow: hidden;
}
ul.progress-bar::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 5px;
  background: #777;
  width: 5px;
  height: 100vh;
}
ul.progress-bar li {
  background: #000;
  border-radius: 100px;
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
  z-index: 1;
  position: relative;
}
ul.progress-bar li.stop ~ li {
  background: #777;
}
ul.progress-bar li.stop ~ li::after {
  height: 0;
}
ul.progress-bar li::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 5px;
  background: #000;
  width: 5px;
  height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<ul class="progress-bar">
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li class="stop"></li>
    <li></li>
</ul>
```

For some reason, the bottom segment doesn't seem to show up in the stacksnippet, so here it is on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Kredit/55vex4ur/).

Comment: All answers were good, but I went with yours and adapted it a bit, so it fits better to my wishes :) You can check out what I have done here: http://jsfiddle.net/hy51q81r/1/

Comment: small bug though, if you want to print a number inside the circle, the line overlaps it because of position absolute..

Answer (score 10):

Here is a CSS solution with very minimal no. of elements. In this approach we use a combination of `linear-gradients` and `radial-gradients` to produce the vertical line and the dots.

The parent `#progress-bar` element produces the lightgreen (initial) line and circles while the same gradients are added to the child `#progress-now` element which is positioned absolutely with respect to the parent. The only difference is that the `height` of the `#progress-now` element is determined based on the `value` attribute.

The solution would work even when the values are in fractions. I know you are using it for step tracker but this is just an added use (blowing my own trumpet :D).

```js
window.onload = function() {
  var val = document.getElementById('progress-now').getAttribute('value');
  var progress = (val * 50 > 400) ? 400 : val*50; /* 50 is 1/8th of height, 400 is height */
  document.getElementById('progress-now').setAttribute('style', 'height: ' + progress + 'px');
}
```

```css
#progress-bar {
  position: relative;
  height: 400px;
  width: 200px;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, lightgreen 99.9%, transparent 99.9%), radial-gradient(circle at 50% 50%, lightgreen 25%, transparent 30%);
  background-position: 50% 0%, 50% 15px; /* 15px is 30% of 50px */
  background-size: 5px 100%, 50px 50px; /* 5px is the thickness of the bar, 50px is 1/8th of the height */
  background-repeat: no-repeat, repeat-y;
}
#progress-now {
  position: absolute;
  width: 200px;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, darkgreen 99.9%, transparent 99.9%), radial-gradient(circle at 50% 50%, darkgreen 25%, transparent 30%);
  background-position: 50% 0%, 50% 15px;
  background-size: 5px 100%, 50px 50px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat, repeat-y;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/prefixfree/1.0.7/prefixfree.min.js"></script>
<div id='progress-bar'>
  <div id='progress-now' value='1.85'></div>
</div>
```

---

Below is a version with **fill-up animation effect**.

```js
window.onload = function() {
  var val = 0, progress = 0;

  function progressBar() {
    val += 0.005;
    progress = (val * 50 > 400) ? 400 : val * 50; /* 50 is 1/8th of height, 400 is height */
    document.getElementById('progress-now').setAttribute('style', 'height: ' + progress + 'px');
    if (val <= 8) anim = window.requestAnimationFrame(progressBar);
  }
  
  progressBar();
}
```

```css
#progress-bar {
  position: relative;
  height: 400px;
  width: 200px;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, lightgreen 99.9%, transparent 99.9%), radial-gradient(circle at 50% 50%, lightgreen 25%, transparent 30%);
  background-position: 50% 0%, 50% 15px; /* 15px is 30% of 50px */
  background-size: 5px 100%, 50px 50px; /* 5px is the thickness of the bar, 50px is 1/8th of the height */
  background-repeat: no-repeat, repeat-y;
}
#progress-now {
  position: absolute;
  width: 200px;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, darkgreen 99.9%, transparent 99.9%), radial-gradient(circle at 50% 50%, darkgreen 25%, transparent 30%);
  background-position: 50% 0%, 50% 15px;
  background-size: 5px 100%, 50px 50px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat, repeat-y;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/prefixfree/1.0.7/prefixfree.min.js"></script>
<div id='progress-bar'>
  <div id='progress-now'></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks @ScottKaye. The flexbox approach was nice too :)

Answer (score 7):

### CSS

My CSS solution is based around multiple `div`'s which allow you to have as many as you like and determine how many are completed.

```css
.complete {
  width: 5px;
  height: 50px;
  position: relative;
  background: green;
  margin-left: 8px;
}
.complete:after {
  content: '';
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -7.5px;
  left: -8px;
  background: green;
  z-index: 100;
}
.not_complete {
  width: 5px;
  height: 50px;
  background: lightgreen;
  position: relative;
  margin-left: 8px;
}
.not_complete:after {
  content: '';
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -7.5px;
  left: -8px;
  background: lightgreen;
  z-index: 100;
}
```

```html
<div class="progress">
  <div class="complete"></div>
  <div class="complete"></div>
  <div class="not_complete"></div>
  <div class="not_complete"></div>
  <div class="not_complete"></div>
  <div class="not_complete"></div>
  <div class="not_complete"></div>
  <div class="not_complete"></div>
</div>
```

### SVG

This is also possible using a SVG `g` element and using it with different fills.

Just remember that the height of the SVG needs to be the same or greater than all the elements put together.

```html
<svg width="20" height="445" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
  <defs>
    <g id="completed">
      <line x1="0" y1="5" x2="0" y2="40" style="stroke:green;stroke-width:3;" />
      <circle style="fill:green; stroke-width:0;" cx="0" cy="50" r="10" />
    </g>
    <g id="not_complete">
      <line x1="0" y1="5" x2="0" y2="40" style="stroke:lightgreen;stroke-width:3;" />
      <circle style="fill:lightgreen; stroke-width:0;" cx="0" cy="50" r="10" />
    </g>
  </defs>

  <use x="10" y="00" xlink:href="#completed" />
  <use x="10" y="55" xlink:href="#completed" />
  <use x="10" y="110" xlink:href="#not_complete" />
  <use x="10" y="165" xlink:href="#not_complete" />
  <use x="10" y="220" xlink:href="#not_complete" />
  <use x="10" y="275" xlink:href="#not_complete" />
  <use x="10" y="330" xlink:href="#not_complete" />
  <use x="10" y="385" xlink:href="#not_complete" />
</svg>
```

Comment: This is exactly what I meant, vote up from me, I think this is the best solution.

Comment: Much of that CSS is redundant.  Could you condense it a bit? :)

Comment: I understand i could minify it but leaving it like it is does help the user understand how its positioned and the like. If you feel the CSS could be minified without impacting its ease of readability then message me on chat and we can go over it :)

Answer (score 7):

My comment turned into an answer.
It is  using an hidden `<progress>` with behind an emty `<div>` to draw the desired output.

This is not very flexible, CSS must be written in advance for the 5/6 options : 0,20%,40%,60%,80%,100%

```css
.hide-it {
  position: absolute;
  left: -100%;
}

#myprogress {
  height: 25em;
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  width: 0.5em;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #00B18E 0%, #CFF8F0 0%, #CFF8F0);
  margin: 1em 9em 1em 1em;
  color:#00B18E;
  box-shadow:0 0 15em 1em black;
}
#myprogress:after {
  content: '     Progress 0%';
  position:relative;
  z-index: 1;
  white-space: pre;
  top:-1%;
}
#myprogress:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  top: -0.2em;
  left: -.25em;
  width: 1em;
  height: 1em;
  border-radius: 50%;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 15px #00B18E;
}

[value="20"] + #myprogress {
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #00B18E 20%, #CFF8F0 20%, #CFF8F0);
}

[value="20"] + #myprogress:before {
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 15px #00B18E, 0 5em 0 0 #00B18E;
}
[value="20"] + #myprogress:after {
  content:'     Progress 20%';
  top:19%;
}

[value="40"] + #myprogress {
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #00B18E 40%, #CFF8F0 40%, #CFF8F0);
}

[value="40"] + #myprogress:before {
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 15px #00B18E, 0 5em 0 0 #00B18E, 0 10em 0 0 #00B18E;
}
[value="40"] + #myprogress:after {
  content:'     Progress 40%';
  top:39%;
}

[value="60"] + #myprogress {
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #00B18E 60%, #CFF8F0 60%, #CFF8F0);
}
[value="60"] + #myprogress:before {
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 15px #00B18E, 0 5em 0 0 #00B18E, 0 10em 0 0 #00B18E, 0 15em 0 0 #00B18E;
}
[value="60"] + #myprogress:after {
  content:'     Progress 60%';
  top:59%;
}
[value="80"] + #myprogress {
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #00B18E 80%, #CFF8F0 80%, #CFF8F0);
}
[value="80"] + #myprogress:before {
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 15px #00B18E, 0 5em 0 0 #00B18E, 0 10em 0 0 #00B18E, 0 15em 0 0 #00B18E, 0 20em 0 0 #00B18E;
}
[value="80"] + #myprogress:after {
  content:'     Progress 80%';
  top:79%;
}
[value="100"] + #myprogress {
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #00B18E 100%, #CFF8F0 100%, #CFF8F0);
}
[value="100"] + #myprogress:before {
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 15px #00B18E, 0 5em 0 0 #00B18E, 0 10em 0 0 #00B18E, 0 15em 0 0 #00B18E, 0 20em 0 0 #00B18E, 0 25em 0 0 #00B18E;
}
[value="100"] + #myprogress:after {
  content:'     Progress 100%';
  top:99%;
}
```

```html
<progress class="hide-it" value="0" max="100">
</progress>
  <div id="myprogress"></div>
<progress class="hide-it" value="20" max="100">
</progress>
  <div id="myprogress"></div>
<progress class="hide-it" value="40" max="100">
</progress>
  <div id="myprogress"></div>
<progress class="hide-it" value="60" max="100">
</progress>
  <div id="myprogress"></div>
<progress class="hide-it" value="80" max="100">
</progress>
  <div id="myprogress"></div>
<progress class="hide-it" value="100" max="100">
</progress>
  <div id="myprogress"></div>
```

[The codepen to play with](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/xwRyrm)

Comment: Actually, I am not the question's OP but I like that solution :) As you have rightly said, it is not very fluid but OP indicated that its a 8 step progress bar which indicates the CSS can be pre-written.

Answer (score 5):

You can use `box-shadow` to achieve this effect.This can be achieved using a single element as it uses `box-shadow`s but it will be hard to change the color using javascript

Note:I used jquery to only show the effect of adding more to the progress bar
click anywhere on the body to see the result

```js
$('body').click(function () {
    var x = parseInt($('.progressNow').css('top')) + 10;
    $('.progressNow').css({
        top: x
    })
    if (x > 90 - 800) {      $('.circle').css('background','#00b164')
    }
    if(x > 180 -800){
        $('.circle').css('box-shadow','0 90px 0 0 #00b164, 0 180px 0 0 #8fe4bf, 0 270px 0 0 #8fe4bf, 0 360px 0 0 #8fe4bf, 0 450px 0 0 #8fe4bf, 0 540px 0 0 #8fe4bf')
    }
    if(x > 270 -800){
        $('.circle').css('box-shadow','0 90px 0 0 #00b164, 0 180px 0 0 #00b164, 0 270px 0 0 #8fe4bf, 0 360px 0 0 #8fe4bf, 0 450px 0 0 #8fe4bf, 0 540px 0 0 #8fe4bf')
    }    
})
```

```css
#progress {
    overflow:hidden;
    width:15px;
    padding-left:5px;
    height:800px;
    position: relative;
}
#progress .progressBar {
    height: 800px;
    width: 6px;
    background: #8fe4bf;
    position: absolute;
}
#progress .progressNow {
    height: 800px;
    top:-800px;
    width: 6px;
    background: #00b164;
    position: absolute;
}
.circle{
    content:"";
    width: 16px;
    height: 16px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background: #8fe4bf;
    display: block;
    margin-left: -5px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 90px;
    box-shadow:0 90px 0 0 #8fe4bf, 0 180px 0 0 #8fe4bf, 0 270px 0 0 #8fe4bf, 0 360px 0 0 #8fe4bf, 0 450px 0 0 #8fe4bf, 0 540px 0 0 #8fe4bf;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="progress">
    <div class="progressBar"></div>
    <div class="circle"></div>
    <div class="progressNow" value="1"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 5):

#### SVG

Here is a functional scroll bar with series of dots.
The dots are a single path.
The scrolling effect on the bar is a linear gradient modified through javascript.
The percentage text is a svg text element, and javascript modifies the y attribute of this element.

(I spent to much time on this solution)

```js
var start = document.getElementById("gradstart");
var stop = document.getElementById("gradstop");
var max = Math.max(document.body.scrollHeight, document.body.offsetHeight,
  document.documentElement.clientHeight, document.documentElement.scrollHeight, document.documentElement.offsetHeight);
max -= document.documentElement.clientHeight;

var process = document.getElementById("process");

function gradientScroll() {
  var top = (window.pageYOffset || document.documentElement.scrollTop)
  var amount = Math.round((top / max) * 100.0);
  process.setAttribute("y", (amount) + "%");
  process.innerHTML = amount + "%";
  start.setAttribute("offset", amount + "%");
  stop.setAttribute("offset", amount + "%");
}

window.addEventListener("scroll", function() {
  window.requestAnimationFrame(gradientScroll);
});
```

```html
<svg height="800px" viewBox="0 0 100 700" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
  <defs>
    <linearGradient x1="0" x2="0" y1="0%" y2="100%" id="grad">
      <stop id="gradstart" offset="50%" stop-color="firebrick" />
      <stop id="gradstop" offset="50%" stop-color="pink" />
    </linearGradient>
  </defs>
  <path fill="url(#grad)" d="m20,0 0,50 
                       a10 10 0 0 0 0,20
                       v50
                       a10 10 0 0 0 0,20
                       v50
                       a10 10 0 0 0 0,20
                       v50
                       a10 10 0 0 0 0,20
                       v50
                       a10 10 0 0 0 0,20
                       v50
                       a10 10 0 0 0 0,20
                       v50
                       a10 10 0 0 0 0,20
                       v50
                       a10 10 0 0 0 0,20
                       v50
                       a10 10 0 0 0 0,20
                       v50
                       a10 10 0 0 0 0,20
                       h5
                       a10 10 0 0 0 0,-20
                       v-50
                       a10 10 0 0 0 0,-20
                       v-50
                       a10 10 0 0 0 0,-20
                       v-50
                       a10 10 0 0 0 0,-20
                       v-50
                       a10 10 0 0 0 0,-20
                       v-50
                       a10 10 0 0 0 0,-20
                       v-50
                       a10 10 0 0 0 0,-20
                       v-50
                       a10 10 0 0 0 0,-20
                       v-50
                       a10 10 0 0 0 0,-20
                       v-50
                       a10 10 0 0 0 0,-20
                       v-100Z"></path>
  <text id="process" text-anchor="middle" x="60" y="50">Amount</text>
</svg>
```