# Custom ol-list CSS styling with flex alighning

Tags: css, html, html-lists, vertical-alignment, flexbox

Stunned with case when need to write point-less ol list in rounded circe connected with line below, like this:

[image: needed]

I've tried to make it with pseudo-elements but always stunned to many difficulties especially alignment.

The idea to write it as much simple as possible and try to use flex.
Or, at least I wanna listen the opinon that alighnment possible only with display:table.

Thanks.

Code is below

HTML

```
<ol>
  <li>
    <div class="number-round fw-semi-bold">1</div>
    <p>Lorem upsum1</p>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="number-round fw-semi-bold">1</div>
    <p>Lorem upsum imsum huipsum. Lorem upsum imsum huipsum. </br> Lorem upsum imsum huipsum.</p>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="number-round fw-semi-bold">1</div>
    <p>Lorem upsum</p>
  </li>
</ol>
```

SCSS

```
.ol {
  list-style-type: none;
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: stretch;

  > li {
    display: flex;
    height: 3rem;
    align-items: center;
  }

  &:before {
    position: absolute;
    top: 10vw;
    bottom: 10vw;
    left: 75px;
    width: 1px;
    content: " ";
    margin-left: -4px;
    background-color: #111;
    z-index: -1;
  }

  .number-round {
    vertical-align: middle;
    // display: table-cell;
    font-size: 90%;
    z-index: 100;
    text-align: center;

    & :before {
      border: 1px solid #111;
      border-radius: 50%;
      background: black;
      display: inline-block;
      width: 28px;
      height: 28px;
      margin: 0 14px 0 18px;
      padding-top: 1px;
      font-size: 13px;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: First of all, drop the `.ol`. You are trying to target an `ol` directly, not something with the `class="ol"`.

Answer (score 0):

It took some playing around with `:before` (you were on the right track there!), but I started with simplifying your HTML and removing your CSS.

It should look something like this:

[image]

I ended up with this HTML:

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <ol>
        <li>
            <p>Lorem upsum1</p>
        </li>
        <li>
            <p>Lorem upsum imsum huipsum. Lorem upsum imsum huipsum. Lorem upsum imsum huipsum.</p>
        </li>
        <li>
            <p>Lorem upsum</p>
        </li>
    </ol>
</div>
```

And this CSS (I don't know scss, so you'd have to translate it before you use it, I guess):

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
#wrapper {
    height: 300px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

ol li {
    height: 60px;
}

ol li p {
    padding-left: 20px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    display: inline-block;
}

ol:before {
    content:"";
    width: 1px;
    height: 120px;
    margin-top: 20px;
    background: black;
    position:absolute;
    left:33px;
    z-index: -2;
}
ol li:before {
    content:"";
    width: 26px;
    height: 26px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    background: #fff;
    position: absolute;
    left: 19px;
    margin-top: 9px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    z-index: -1;
}

ol li:nth-child(2) {
    margin-top: -14px;
}

ol li:nth-child(2):before {
    margin-top: 18px;
}
```

[Working example](http://jsfiddle.net/5dkugpt9/)

It's not very responsive, since you have to position the circles with `margin-top` if it's more than 1 line, but I'm pretty sure you can use this as a stepping stone to your final solution.

You could also look at [my own question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32825243/progress-bar-made-of-solid-line-with-dots-as-steps) from a few weeks ago, where I solve it with creating two lists. The answers might be useful if my answer is not sufficient.