# Vertical line with dots in ends and between

Tags: css

I have been searching for a solution for this both here, and on google with no success.

I want to create a Vertical line which has dots in the ends and a few along the line.

img for example:

[image: horizontal line with dots]

how can I achieve this with css ? 
I can do a dotted line with spacing, but I have no idea how to create the line also, and if that is even possible ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32825243/progress-bar-made-of-solid-line-with-dots-as-steps/32825870#32825870

Comment: @Harry im not looking for a progress bar as such, though it is supposed to follow the height of the box it is in. and have a dot for each row of data.

Comment: @andrelange91, I think you mean vertical line, not horizontal!

Comment: It should be easy to remove the progress related stuff is what I felt.

Comment: ... yes i mean vertical ! @AngelosChalaris.

Comment: @andrelange91: Was re-reading your comment and I have a question. Have you got (or can use) multiple elements like in Angelos' demo or do you have one single element with text that wraps around and you need this line + dots to appear inside it such that the dot appears once for each line?

Comment: @Harry multiple elements. But i think i can tweak the answer from Angelos.

Comment: Ok, that's good then @andrelange91. By the way for your comment on how to change the line color in his demo, change the color in this line `border-left: 2px solid black;`. For changing the circle's color add `color: <whatever>` under `.bar>li:before`.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Here's a quick snippet that might help you with your problem:

```css
.bar {
  list-style: none;
}
.bar >li {
  position: relative;
}
.bar>li:before {
  content: '\25CF';
  margin-right: 10px;
  font-size: 20px;
}
.bar>li:after {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  content: '';
  border-left: 2px solid black;
  margin-left: 5px;
  height: 100%;
}
.bar >li:first-of-type:after {
  top: 50%;
}
.bar >li:last-of-type:after {
  top: -50%;
}
```

```html
<ul class="bar">
  <li>element 1</li>
  <li>element 2</li>
  <li>element 3</li>
  <li>element 4</li>
  <li>element 5</li>
</ul>
```

The idea is that you use a list and each element's bullet is replaced with a `:before` symbol of a [Unicode black circle](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/25CF/index.htm), while each `:after` selector for the elements contains the element's share of the vertical line. The first and last list elements have an extra rule to truncate their border-line, so that it does not go past the black circle.

Tweak it a bit to get the exact effect you want!

Comment: this sort of works, though it doesn't have a dot at the start and beginning, and i seem to be unable to give the line a color.. ?

Comment: This works great. Thanks. But my text should appear in multiple lines and If I use this snippet with line breaks in my text, the second line first word is not appearing under start of the first-line word instead it starts before the vertical line. Where should I adjust it?

Answer (score 5):

```html
<style>
  svg {
    background-color: black;
  }
  .dotted-line {
    fill: none;
    stroke: orange;
    stroke-width: 2;
    marker: url(#circle-marker);
  }
  #circle-marker circle {
    fill: orange;
    stroke; orange;
  }
</style>
<svg height="40" width="190">
  <polyline class="dotted-line" points="20,20 70,20 120,20 170,20"/>
  <marker id="circle-marker" markerWidth="8" markerHeight="8" refX="5" refY="5">
    <circle class="foreground" cx="5" cy="5" r="3" />
  </marker>
</svg>
```

(I took "horisontal" at face value; it is trivial to make it vertical.)

Look up [`marker` SVG element](https://www.w3.org/TR/svg-markers/), and `marker-start`, `marker-end`, `marker-mid` SVG attributes. `marker` attribute here combines the three attributes (for brevity, since they're all identical).

Comment: is it something i have to download and install ? or is it build in to html/css ?

Comment: It's built in; but seeing what you want it for, it won't help you. Use Angelos Chalaris's solution.

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an old question but I would like to provide another possible solution

```css
.element {
 display: flex;
 flex-direction: column;
 align-items: center;
}

.circle {
 border-radius: 50%;
 width: 15px;
 height: 15px;
}

.circle-black {
 background-color: black;
}

.vline {
 border-left: 3px solid;
 height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="element">
 <div class="vline"></div>
 <div class="circle circle-black"></div>
</div>
```

The main idea is that a dot is simply a rounded square (to create bigger or smaller dots simply adjust width and height in the `cicrle` class, but preserve its squareness) and the conjunction element is a vertical line. With this format you can easily add or remove lines and apply colors to both lines (add a border-color rule) and dots.