# How to create custom border design in css

Tags: css, border

First of all see the below image

[image]

I have tried that center border along with all sections. But can't get idea about the little rounds in border at start of border,end of border and every sections. 
See the result that i tried in below image

[image]

Posted sample of code here

**HTML:**

```
 <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 work_container">
 <div class="work_content">
  <div class="work_content_img">
   <img src="https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/736x/c7/2f/9a/c72f9a9fb1bfca41d0eabdc07f2f1815.jpg">   
    </div>
   <div class="work_content_txt">
    <div class="work_content_txt_two">
       <h1>step 3</h1>
       <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
       <p>Duis eleifend elit quam. Maecenas at metus leo.</p>
       <p class="itlc_text_two">Quisque lacinia eleifend aliquam. Praesent rhoncus, incidunt auctor.</p>
        </div>
        </div>
        </div>
       </div>
```

**CSS**

```
img{
   max-width:100%;
   }
.work_content {
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
}
.work_container:before{
        content: '';
        border-right: 2px solid #e6e6e6;
        height: 90%;
        position: absolute;
        top: 5%;
        left: 50%;
        z-index:9999;
 }
.work_content .work_content_img {
  float: left;
  width:50%;

 }
 .work_content .work_content_txt {
   float: right;
   width: 42%; 
   padding: 25px;
   background: #fff;
   display: table-cell;
 }
  .work_content .work_content_txt .work_content_txt_two h1 {
    color: #F16A70;
    font-family: oswald;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 22px;
 }
 .work_content .work_content_txt .work_content_txt_two p {
   font-family: georgia;
   color: #707070;
   font-size: 18px;
   margin-bottom: 0;
 }
 .work_content .work_content_txt .work_content_txt_two .itlc_text_two {
    font-style: italic;
    font-family: sans serif;
    color: #707070;
   font-size: 19px;
   margin-top: 0;
 }
    .itlc_text_two {
   font-style: italic;
   font-family: sans-serif;
   color: 707070;
   font-size: 18px;
   margin-top: 0;
 }
```

My question is how to get little round shapes in that border as like in image. Thanks in advance

Comment: Any one of the answers here should help - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32825243/progress-bar-made-of-solid-line-with-dots-as-steps/32825870#32825870. They implement a progress bar but you can easily remove the progress related stuff and just retain the line with dots.

Comment: And another one - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41845953/vertical-line-with-dots-in-ends-and-between#comment70877705_41845953

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a solution using `:before` and `:after` pseudo-elements

```css
img{
   max-width:100%;
   }
.work_content {
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
  position: relative;
}
.vert {
 position: absolute;
  width: 2px;
  height: 90%;
  background: #aaa;
  left: 50%;
  top: 5%;
}
.vert:before {
  content: " ";
  width: 11px;
  height: 11px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: block;
  border: 2px solid #aaa;
  position: relative;
  left: -5px;
  top: -11px;
}
.vert:after {
  content: " ";
  width: 11px;
  height: 11px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: block;
  border: 2px solid #aaa;
  position: relative;
  left: -5px;
  top: calc(100% - 11px);
}

.work_content .work_content_img {
  float: left;
  width:50%;

 }
 .work_content .work_content_txt {
   float: right;
   width: 42%; 
   padding: 25px;
   background: #fff;
   display: table-cell;
 }
  .work_content .work_content_txt .work_content_txt_two h1 {
    color: #F16A70;
    font-family: oswald;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 22px;
 }
 .work_content .work_content_txt .work_content_txt_two p {
   font-family: georgia;
   color: #707070;
   font-size: 18px;
   margin-bottom: 0;
 }
 .work_content .work_content_txt .work_content_txt_two .itlc_text_two {
    font-style: italic;
    font-family: sans serif;
    color: #707070;
   font-size: 19px;
   margin-top: 0;
 }
    .itlc_text_two {
   font-style: italic;
   font-family: sans-serif;
   color: 707070;
   font-size: 18px;
   margin-top: 0;
 }
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-xs-12 work_container">
 <div class="work_content">
  <div class="vert"></div>
  <div class="work_content_img">
   <img src="https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/736x/c7/2f/9a/c72f9a9fb1bfca41d0eabdc07f2f1815.jpg">   
    </div>
   <div class="work_content_txt">
    <div class="work_content_txt_two">
       <h1>step 3</h1>
       <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
       <p>Duis eleifend elit quam. Maecenas at metus leo.</p>
       <p class="itlc_text_two">Quisque lacinia eleifend aliquam. Praesent rhoncus, incidunt auctor.</p>
        </div>
        </div>
        </div>
       </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use more pseudos.
:after to draw the first dot, and then h1:before to draw others :

```css
img {
  max-width: 100%;
}
.work_content {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
.work_container:before {
  content: '';
  border-right: 2px solid #e6e6e6;
  height: 90%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 5%;
  left: 50%;
  z-index: 9999;
}
.work_container:after,
.work_content_txt h1:before {
  content: '';
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px 2px #e6e6e6, 0 0 0 10px white;
  background: white;
  border-radius: 50%;
  ;
  height: 16px;
  width: 16px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 5%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -8px;
  z-index: 9999;
}
.work_content_txt h1:before {
  top: auto;
}
.work_content .work_content_img {
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
}
.work_content .work_content_txt {
  float: right;
  width: 42%;
  padding: 25px;
  background: #fff;
  display: table-cell;
}
.work_content .work_content_txt .work_content_txt_two h1 {
  color: #F16A70;
  font-family: oswald;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 22px;
}
.work_content .work_content_txt .work_content_txt_two p {
  font-family: georgia;
  color: #707070;
  font-size: 18px;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
.work_content .work_content_txt .work_content_txt_two .itlc_text_two {
  font-style: italic;
  font-family: sans serif;
  color: #707070;
  font-size: 19px;
  margin-top: 0;
}
.itlc_text_two {
  font-style: italic;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  color: 707070;
  font-size: 18px;
  margin-top: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 work_container">
  <div class="work_content">
    <div class="work_content_img">
      <img src="https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/736x/c7/2f/9a/c72f9a9fb1bfca41d0eabdc07f2f1815.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="work_content_txt">
      <div class="work_content_txt_two">
        <h1>step 3</h1>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
        <p>Duis eleifend elit quam. Maecenas at metus leo.</p>
        <p class="itlc_text_two">Quisque lacinia eleifend aliquam. Praesent rhoncus, incidunt auctor.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```