# Create a vertical line with a circle in it and text on sides aligned to circles

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to implement the following on my website:

[image]

Obviously this should be able to go on for more iterations, I don't really know what to google for, I found a way to create a line, but I have no idea how to combine that with Circles and how to make those aligned with the text.

Final code:

```
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style-type: none;
}

ul li div {
    width: 50%;
    float: left;
    text-align: center;
}

ul li .zero-left {
    position: relative;
    color: #EB908B;
    width: 30%;
    text-align: right;
    padding-right: 20px;
}

ul li .zero-right {
    border-left: 3px solid #3C4C4C;
    position: relative;
    color: #3C4C4C;
    width: 70%;
    padding-left: 15px;
    text-align: left;
}

ul li .first {
    position: relative;
    color: #EB908B;
    width: 30%;
    text-align: right;
    padding-right: 20px;
}

ul li .second {
    border-left: 3px solid #3C4C4C;
    position: relative;
    width: 70%;
    padding-left: 15px;
    text-align: left;
}

ul li .second p {
    color: #EB908B;
    position: relative;
    text-align: left;
}

ul li .first::before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    right: -11.5px;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    border-radius: 150%;
    border: 2px solid #3C4C4C;
    background: #3C4C4C;
    z-index:9999
}
```

Comment: you can use this:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/41982653/4206079 as a base

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `after` pseudo-element to put circle. Here I made an example with `after` solution.

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8v5oh1ed/1/)

Comment: ok, I've updated it a little bit (width 30% for left and width 70% for left), thanks a lot!