# How do I show step description on the progress bar?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I currently have this, a bootstrap progress bar:

```
<div class="progress">
   <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-success" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="1" aria-valuemin="1" aria-valuemax="8" style="width: 20%;">
      Step 1 of 8
   </div>
</div>
```

The I have some tabs and each time one is active, i run this:

```
jQuery('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('show.bs.tab', function (e) {
  var step = jQuery(e.target).data('step');
  var percent = (parseInt(step) / 8) * 100;
  jQuery('.progress-bar').css({width: percent + '%'});
  jQuery('.progress-bar').text("Step " + step + " di 8");
});
```

That's fine and it works but how about having the description of each step on top?

**UPDATE**

This is a [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/b2eyxgf9/3/)

Something along those lines[image]

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your attempt.

Comment: @andreas building a jsFiddle, will update

Comment: question has been updated with a https://jsfiddle.net/b2eyxgf9/3/ @andreas

Comment: Ok, what do you mean with "details on top"?

Comment: @andreas I mean description

Comment: Where is the description in your fiddle? You need to be more clearer about what you try to achieve...

Comment: @andreas i haven't put the description because I don't know where to put it or I would have built it myself. I don't see any point in just placing html randomly. I have a bar which follows 8 steps. Each step should have a description. While I am getting down votes and writing this comment, I am also checking how to do it myself by the way, thanks

Comment: We can't really read your mind with this, you must know where you want to put the description and how you intend for it to work? Try something, give us something a bit more solid to go on. Why not put the description in the tab?

Comment: see if the updated question with an image example is of any help @AndyHolmes

Comment: @andreas  
see if the updated question with an image example is of any help

Comment: Why not put the step details in a `data-` tag and on change of the tab read that info and display it inside a div or similar?

Comment: @AndyHolmes yes I thought of that but that will mean only having the description of the current step, while I want to tell the users what they will find on the next steps too

Comment: @AndyHolmes it is something along those lines http://www.prepbootstrap.com/bootstrap-template/steps-navigation-progressbar

Comment: So put it in the tab instead of "Step N"

Comment: @robertoMarras see if the answer below helps

Comment: `That's fine and it works but how about having the description of each step on top?` Which description are you referring to? The description inside each tab? Or something else.

Comment: @Rüzgar really trying to build something along the lines of the image attached within the quetsion

Comment: Like I say, put it in the tab and style the tab

Comment: @AndyHolmes we cannot do that, what is the width of the whole tabs list compared to the step division of the progress bar? It isn't that easy

Comment: I really wanto help, and i believe i can. But i think we do not understand each other. :) That's why I'm asking again. What is the **description** of each step?

Comment: Pretty easy to do with Flexbox @RobertoMarras

Comment: @AndyHolmes could you elaborate it more in an answer? I would love to use flexbox actually

Comment: @AndyHolmes found this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32825243/progress-bar-made-of-solid-line-with-dots-as-steps

Comment: @RobertoMarras I've added an answer for a good way of achieving this with flexbox as you asked

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a way of doing this with flexbox, nice and simple:

```js
jQuery('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('show.bs.tab', function(e) {
    var step = jQuery(e.target).data('step');
    var percent = (parseInt(step) / 8) * 100;
    jQuery('.progress-bar').css({
        width: percent + '%'
    });
    jQuery('.progress-bar').text("Step " + step + " di 8");
});
```

```css
#wiz_menu {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
}

#wiz_menu li {
    width: 100%;
    float: none;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="progress">
    <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-success" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="1" aria-valuemin="1" aria-valuemax="8" style="width: 20%;">
        Step 1 of 8
    </div>
</div>

<ul id="wiz_menu" class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li class="active"><a href="#step1" data-toggle="tab" data-step="1">Your Details</a></li>
    <li><a href="#step2" data-toggle="tab" data-step="2">Bank Details</a></li>
    <li><a href="#step3" data-toggle="tab" data-step="3">Another step</a></li>
    <li><a href="#step4" data-toggle="tab" data-step="4">Step 4</a></li>
    <li><a href="#step5" data-toggle="tab" data-step="5">Step 5</a></li>
    <li><a href="#step6" data-toggle="tab" data-step="6">Step 6</a></li>
    <li><a href="#step7" data-toggle="tab" data-step="7">Step 7</a></li>
    <li><a href="#step8" data-toggle="tab" data-step="8">Step 8</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: oh this is beautiful! Thanks

Comment: No problem @RobertoMarras :)

Answer (score 1):

Just added some code to your jsfiddle, hope this helps. You have to amend it as per your requirement.

```js
    var maxProgressBarWidth = 0;
    jQuery('.nav li').each(function() {
     maxProgressBarWidth += jQuery(this).outerWidth();
    });
    jQuery('.progress').width(maxProgressBarWidth);
    jQuery('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('show.bs.tab', function (e) {
      var step = jQuery(e.target).data('step');
      var percent = (parseInt(step) / 8) * 100;
      jQuery('.tab-desc').removeClass('active').filter('[data-step=' + step + ']').addClass('active');
      jQuery('.progress-bar').css({width: percent + '%'});
      jQuery('.progress-bar').text("Step " + step + " di 8");
    });
```

```css
.tab-desc {
  display: none;
}
.tab-desc.active {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="progress">
   <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-success" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="1" aria-valuemin="1" aria-valuemax="8" style="width: 20%;">
      Step 1 of 8
   </div>
</div>

<ul id="wiz_menu" class="nav nav-tabs">
                   <li class="active"><a href="#step1" data-toggle="tab" data-step="1">Step 1</a></li>
                   <li><a href="#step2" data-toggle="tab" data-step="2">Step 2</a></li>
                   <li><a href="#step3" data-toggle="tab" data-step="3">Step 3</a></li>
                   <li><a href="#step4" data-toggle="tab" data-step="4">Step 4</a></li>
                   <li><a href="#step5" data-toggle="tab" data-step="5">Step 5</a></li>
                   <li><a href="#step6" data-toggle="tab" data-step="6">Step 6</a></li>
                   <li><a href="#step7" data-toggle="tab" data-step="7">Step 7</a></li>
                   <li><a href="#step8" data-toggle="tab" data-step="8">Step 8</a></li>
                </ul>
                
<div class="tab-desc active" data-step="1">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Illo quia explicabo deserunt a, quod repellat necessitatibus quisquam perferendis unde quo! Quibusdam officia impedit quam, odio vero suscipit voluptatibus, neque ex!
</div>
<div class="tab-desc" data-step="2">
  ecessitatibus quisquam perferendis unde quo! Quibusdam officia impedit quam, odio vero suscipit voluptatibus, neque ex!
</div>
<div class="tab-desc" data-step="3">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur Quibusdam officia impedit quam, odio vero suscipit voluptatibus, neque ex!
</div>
<div class="tab-desc" data-step="4">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Illo quia explicabo deserunt a, quod repellat necessitatibus quisquam perferendis unde quo! Quibusdam officia impedit quam, odio vero suscipit voluptatibus, neque ex!
</div>
<div class="tab-desc" data-step="5">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Illo quia explicabo deserunt a, quod repellat necessitatibus quisquam perferendis unde quo! 
</div>
<div class="tab-desc" data-step="6">
   Quibusdam officia impedit quam, odio vero suscipit voluptatibus, neque ex!
</div>
<div class="tab-desc" data-step="7">
  Illo quia explicabo deserunt a, quod repellat necessitatibus quisquam perferendis unde quo! Quibusdam officia impedit quam, odio vero suscipit voluptatibus, neque ex!
</div>
<div class="tab-desc" data-step="8">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur 
</div>
```

EDIT: You can move the markup (html) above the steps tab list and amend/style it as per your screenshot.

Update js to calculate the width of the tabs and set it to progress div

Comment: hey thanks, trying to work this out, I thought of placing the description instead of the tab names, but these are actually hidden in my example. Anyway why is it not diving properly by 8 and not matching the tabs when I do it here https://jsfiddle.net/b2eyxgf9/7/

Comment: @RobertoMarras what do you mean? looks okay to me in your fiddle. Although on the initial load the progress bar has 20% width which makes it look odd when the step 2 is clicked, only a little progress is seen

Comment: if I hit step 8, on my fiddle, it will go all across so if i ever think of using the tabs names as my description, these will not match the position of the progress bar. it is fine on yours tho

Comment: i don't see any difference in mine and yours, i used your code and added a little js to it

Comment: hmm i know what it is, my imac 27" and the width it takes jsfiddle compared to the example above

Comment: it isn't tho, this doesn't answer my question at all. I even don't really see the difference compared to my own jsfiddle in the question. As I replied to another comment above, your answer doesn't solve it, what is the width of the whole tabs list compared to the step division of the progress bar? It isn't that easy

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/142100/discussion-between-webpandit-and-roberto-marras).

Comment: just updated the code snippet to serve your requirement