# Horizontal progess bar with SASS (CSS3)

Tags: html, css, angular, sass

I'm creating and Angular2 component to achieve the following behavior:

[image]

I have an array (strings) in the component named "*stepList*". This is my view:

```
<ul class="step">
    <li class="step__item selected" *ngFor="let step of stepList">
        {{step.label}}
    </li>
</ul>
```

And this is my CSS:

```
.step{
    display: flex;

    &__item {
       display: block;
       padding-left: 25px;
    }
}
```

With the current code, I have the items (names) rendered, but I don't know how to get the line with the circles underneath them.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a `border-bottom` and a pseudo element:

```css
.step{
  display: flex;
}

.step__item {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  padding: 0 12px 25px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid lightgray;
}

.step__item::before {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -5px;
  left: calc(50% - 5px);
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: gray;
  content: '';
}
```

```html
<ul class="step">
    <li class="step__item selected">
        CATEGORIA
    </li>
    
    <li class="step__item selected">
        ATTRIBUTES
    </li>
</ul>
```

And the SCSS code:

```
.step{
    display: flex;

    &__item {
        display: block;
        position: relative;
        padding: 0 12px 25px;
        border-bottom: 1px solid lightgray;

        &::before {
            display: block;
            position: absolute;
            bottom: -5px;
            left: calc(50% - 5px);
            width: 10px;
            height: 10px;
            border-radius: 50%;
            background: gray;
            content: '';
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Padding on the label with a border-bottom to get the line. Create a div with a set height and width (so, for a circle, use the same height and width), forming a square. Add a border-radius of 50% which will make it circular in shape and put the div inside the label. Position absolutely so that it appears over the border-bottom.

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/exjxw7m6/

```
ul.progress-bar {
    height: 300px;
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: space-between;
    overflow: hidden;
    &::after {
        content: "";
        position: absolute;
        top:5px;
        left:5px;
        background: #777;
        height: 5px;
        width: 100%;
    }
    li {
        background: #000;
        border-radius: 100px;
        width: 15px;
        height: 15px;
        z-index: 1;
        position: relative;
        &.stop ~ li {
            background: #777;
            &::after {
                height: 0;
            }
        }
        &::after {
            content: "";
            position: absolute;
            bottom: 0;
            left: 5px;
            background: #000;
            width: 5px;
            height: 100vh;
        }
    }
}
```

more info here: (credit) [Progress bar made of solid line, with dots as steps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32825243/progress-bar-made-of-solid-line-with-dots-as-steps)