# Statu flow circle with multiple rows using css and html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

```css
.multilinePhases {
    display: flow-root;
}
.entityOverviewphase {
    position: relative;
    height: 30px;
}
.entityOverviewphaseleve {
    /* margin-top: -12px; */
    margin-right: 40px;
    float: left;
    height: 40px;
}
.entityOverviewphaseleveColor {
    width: 22px;
    height: 22px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    font-size: 18px;
    color: #aaa;
    line-height: 22px;
    text-align: center;
    background: #ddd;
}

.entityOverviewphaseleveColor::after {
    border-top: 2px solid #999;
    content: "";
    width: 40px;
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    top: 10px;
    left: 22px;
}
.entityOverviewphaseleve:last-child .entityOverviewphaseleveColor::after {
    border-top: 0px solid #999;
    content: "";
    width: 40px;
    height: 20px;
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    top: 10px;
    left: 22px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container" style="padding: 20px;">
 <div class="multilinePhases ng-scope">
 <div class="entityOverviewphase">
  <div class="entityOverviewphaseleve" ng-repeat="">
   <div class="entityOverviewphaseleveColor" style="background-color: #b467e7;"></div>
  </div>
 </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eja6y.jpg)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tFV8w.jpg)

Here is my HTML and CSS code, Please find the below screenshot for more information, I need code like the below images.
can anyone help me to fix this issue? thanks.

Comment: Maybe this one can help you: https://codepen.io/BuddyLReno/pen/NNojRP Simple google search. ..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Progress bar made of solid line, with dots as steps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32825243/progress-bar-made-of-solid-line-with-dots-as-steps)

Comment: Thanks for sharing this, but i need a design like above-shared screenshots.

Comment: You had nothing close to that i gave you . .. Show what you have tried to get  as is in picture

Comment: staus flow circles are dynamic, some time's we may get 1/2/3/4/5/6. and Parent div also dynamic width.

Comment: You can try SVG. and svg line , dasharray, animation