# The position of progress dots are not aligning properly when width is changing

Tags: html, css, progress-bar, css-shapes

We are trying to show progress bar with 7 dots line connected. But progress bar dots are not aligned properly when filling the progress bar line.

```css
.progress-bar {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 40px;
  width: 630px;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #8fe4bf 99.9%, transparent 99.9%), radial-gradient(50px circle at 50%, #8fe4bf 10%, transparent 0%);
  background-position: 0% 50%, 50% 50%;
  background-size: 100% 3px, 80px 70px;
  /* 5px is the thickness of the bar, 50px is 1/8th of the height */
  background-repeat: no-repeat, repeat-x;
}

.progress-now {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #00b164 99.9%, transparent 99.9%), radial-gradient(50px circle at 50% 50%, #00b164 10%, transparent 0%);
  background-position: 0% 50%, 50% 50%;
  background-size: 100% 3px, 80px 50px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat, repeat-x;
  z-index: 1;
  width: 60%;
}
```

```html
<div class="progress-bar">
  <div class="progress-now" id="progress-now" role="progressnow">

  </div>
</div>


<div class="progress-container">
  <div class="progress-bar">
    <div class="progress-now" id="progress-now" role="progressnow">

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[image]

This is filling some thing like this not filling in proper positions how can we do this. We have referred [Progress bar made of solid line, with dots as steps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32825243/progress-bar-made-of-solid-line-with-dots-as-steps) for our code. Please add some suggestions so changing the width do not effect the position of dots on the line. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do it differently and consider `background-clip` like below:

```css
.progress-bar {
  position: relative;
  height: 40px;
  background: 
    linear-gradient(#8fe4bf 0 0) center no-repeat, 
    radial-gradient(circle 5px, #8fe4bf 98%, transparent);
  background-size: 100% 3px, 80px 100%;
}

.progress-bar::before {
  content:"";
  position: absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  bottom:0;
  /* for simplicity I am using the same background 
   and applying a filter to get a different coloration */
  background: inherit;
  filter:brightness(0.7);
  padding-right:calc(100% - var(--p,20%));  /* this will control the progress*/
  background-clip:content-box; /* this will do the magic by clipping the background*/
}
```

```html
<div class="progress-bar"></div>
<div class="progress-bar" style="--p:50%"></div>
<div class="progress-bar" style="--p:80%"></div>
<div class="progress-bar" style="--p:100%"></div>
```

To have fixed number of circles:

```css
.progress-bar {
  position: relative;
  height: 40px;
  background: 
    linear-gradient(#8fe4bf 0 0) center no-repeat, 
    radial-gradient(circle 5px, #8fe4bf 98%, transparent);
  background-size: 100% 3px, calc(100%/var(--n,5)) 100%;
}

.progress-bar::before {
  content:"";
  position: absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  bottom:0;
  /* for simplicity I am using the same background 
   and applying a filter to get a different coloration */
  background: inherit;
  filter:brightness(0.7);
  padding-right:calc(100% - var(--p,20%));  /* this will control the progress*/
  background-clip:content-box; /* this will do the magic by clipping the background*/
}
```

```html
<div class="progress-bar"></div>
<div class="progress-bar" style="--p:50%;--n:10"></div>
<div class="progress-bar" style="--p:80%;--n:3"></div>
<div class="progress-bar" style="--p:100%;--n:8"></div>
```